# Error "classpath resource cannot be opened because it does not exist"

Tags: spring, classpath, file-not-found

I'm trying to develop a simple spring 3 web application with a connection to a small database, just to get used to it!

I defined the database connection in a different xml file and tried to include it in the web.xml file via `<listener>` and `<context-param>` tag.

Now I created a different folder for xml definition files and added it to the classpath, but the error mentioned above is still there!

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: Believe Spring and the JVM.  You don't have it in the right place, no matter what you think.

Comment: where does it have to be? 
Or is there a different way to get this solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is good practice, but I moved the `persons-servlet.xml` into the source folder of my application and now it works.